# How did a clean OS X El Capitan Install on a newly formatted hard drive automatically connect to Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, macbook-pro, osx-el-capitan

I'm currently installing a new SSD in my old MacBook Pro (v 15,1). I created a bootable installer for El Capitan following [Apple's guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

How did my old MacBook Pro automatically connect to my password protected wifi, while booting from a thumbdrive, with an unformatted HD, and without my entering the password?

It connected to the Wifi network that it normally does, but, again, the old drive  was *not* installed, nor was it connected to anything other than a thumbdrive.

Where was the password saved, if not on the old HD? or How'd it connect without my entering the wifi password? Did the bootable thumbdrive copy the wifi information?

Just curious.

Comment: By any chance did you log into iCloud? Failing that, all I have to say is **Strange!**

Comment: No, not yet! it's still copying and going through the set up, but *is* connected. My only guess is that the bootable thumbdrive grabbed the info. I *had* to download El Capitan from the old MPB, the App Store would not let my new iMac download it.

Comment: I just triple-checked and my wifi *is* password protected!

Comment: Just to update. I'm now going through the "new" setup and it *is* asking for a password for the *same* network that it was connected to. It did go through 2 or 3 restarts.

Comment: It stores the WiFi network info in non-volitile RAM (NVRAM); see [this apple.se answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195775/how-to-prevent-storing-the-wifi-password-on-the-recovery-partition/195988#195988). You can reset the NVRAM by [restarting while holding down the Command, Option, P, and R keys](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).